# How can I add and modify a speed variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner.

I'm trying to move a cube in unity with MovePosition, it works just fine, but the problem is that I can't change the speed of the cube.

I have created a public float for speed and I added it to the vector3

```
Vector3 movement = new Vector3(h, 0, v).normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

But it just doesnt seems to work.

I also tried to put it in `MovePosition`, but nothing works.

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 55;
    private Rigidbody rb;


    public void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(h, 0, v).normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;


        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);
    }
}
```

As much as I change the speed, it wont work.

Comment: If your variable is public, it is possible that it is being set by the editor, which takes precedence over the initializer. Are you adjusting it in the script, or are you adjusting it in the Unity editor UI?

Comment: dude DO NOT use fixedUpdate - ever.  apart from other problems, this should just be in Update.

Comment: Step through your program with breakpoints. Are you returning anything with `h` and `v`? Is `movement` showing a positive value? Try removing the `.normalized` and see if that has any effect. Have you tried setting `speed` to an absurd value? `Time.deltaTime` tends to be very small like `1/60` or more.

Comment: @Fattie Your comment is blatantly wrong. There are uses for `FixedUpdate()`. Like doing anything that supplies physics modifications...

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Time.deltaTime` instead of `Time.fixedDeltaTime` inside of the `FixedUpdate` section.

```
Vector3 movement = new Vector3(h, 0, v).normalized * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
```

Comment: Time.deltaTime is the same as Time.fixedDeltaTime when used inside of FixedUpdate. This makes no difference and does not solve his issue.

Comment: If you are manipulating `Rigibody`, you should use `FixedUpdate` to align with the physics ticks. [Unity Answers on this subject](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1014110/why-should-you-update-physics-in-fixedupdate.html)

Comment: Not really Fattie. FixedUpdate is called before every Physycs Update, while Update depends on the user framerate, which could cause inconsistencies.

Comment: @adisib you are correct. I didn't realize that was a feature of `Time.deltaTime`!

Comment: @Fattie That's not true. Rigidbody operations should in fact be called in FixedUpdate to ensure they're framerate-independent.

Comment: nah, that's only in unusual cases (which would be totally irrelevant to the beginner OP) where you are dealing with unusual abstract physics problems.  If it's hard to see why .... don't forget, ***you draw it every update!***  So for a trivial physics problem like "moving it", you must do it, for sure, just before it is drawn each time.

Comment: @Fattie You call it in FixedUpdate because a mobile device may implement the physics operation differently than a desktop pc would. This is because both of those devices are running the game at a different frame rate - I've seen this firsthand.

Comment: @Fattie What part of "modify the rigidbody's velocity or position" is *not* a physics change?

Answer (score 0):

Change these two lines:

```
Vector3 movement = new Vector3(h, 0, v).normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
rb.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);
```

To these:

```
Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
```

See if that helps)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your FixedUpdate function to the following:

```
public void FixedUpdate()
{
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(h, 0, v).normalized;

    rb.velocity = movement * speed;
}
```

Also, do NOT multiply your rigidbody operations by either deltaTime or fixedDeltaTime; they're already framerate-independant, and doing so may cause strange results. Simply calling them in FixedUpdate is sufficient.

Comment: Multiplying by a time delta will not reverse framerate independence. It is actually a good idea to do, because you may want to change your fixed timestep later for performance or simulation accuracy reasons and multiplying by fixedDeltaTime will prevent you from having to change all of your movement modifiers after doing so.

Comment: That's the case for operations like transform.Translate and Vector2.MoveTowards, but not rigidbody operations. See the following references https://answers.unity.com/questions/282004/rigidbodyvelocity-and-timedeltatime.html https://answers.unity.com/questions/227125/rigidbody-and-timedeltatime.html https://answers.unity.com/questions/530478/is-it-even-necessary-to-multiply-by-timedeltatime.html